# How can I ensure that a Spring @EventListener will be invoked first?

Tags: java, spring

When implementing the `ApplicationListener` interface there was an option to implement `Ordered` to specify the order of invocation. 
Now in Spring 4.2 there is an option to use the `@EventListener` annotation. Is there a way to promise that my event listener will be called first?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the [`@Order`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) annotation on the `@EventListener` method:

```
@EventListener(MyEvent.class)
@Order(10)
public void myListener() { /* ... */ }
```

Just as with the `Ordered` interface, lower values have higher priority.

From the [`@EventListener` JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html):

> It is also possible to define the order in which listeners for a certain event are invoked. To do so, add Spring's common `@Order` annotation alongside this annotation.